# What's the difference between direction and orientation?

Tags: word-choice, comparisons

I frequently see these two words in 3D programming. For example:

> the direction of the directional light
>
> the orientation of camera

So, what’s the difference between them?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? What does it tell you?

Comment: I looked, but still don't understand

Comment: Hello zdd, this question can be improved by citing sources you checked before posting it, and explaining why your research results were inadequate for you: are there some reasons due to which you do not understand the difference between these words? Please, clarify.

Comment: You could say "the orientation of the directional light" and the sentence would have an identical meaning to your example without sounding as redundant.

Comment: Probably unrelated: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110301 :)

Comment: This question was asked in 2012, years before English Language & Usage adopted its "please include the research" close reason. A basic rule of law is that statutes adopted at any point in a state's governance not be applied to conduct that occurred before the statutes existed. I think that we should follow a similar rule at EL&U, and for that reason I have voted to reopen this question (which has been of enough interest to attract 18,000 views).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the words are very similar, but there is arguably a subtle distinction.

The word [direction](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/direction_1) suggests movement. While it may refer to a static object, it describes it as if it were or could move toward the described location.

> the position toward which someone or something moves or faces:
>   *Cars were facing every direction after slamming into each other on the icy road.*
>   *I glanced in her direction (= toward her).*
>   *You’re headed in the direction of (= toward) Toronto.*

The word [orientation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/orientation_2) seems to connote that the object is static and there is no suggestion of movement. As noted in a comment to this post, it is a relationship to the environment.

> the position of something in relation to its surroundings:
>   *The church has an east-west orientation (= has one main side facing east and the opposite side facing west).*

There are many cases where either could be used, (even a paraphrase of one of the examples under *direction*)

> *Cars were oriented every which way after slamming into each other on the icy road.*

However, there are many when only one or the other will do.

> *He moved in the direction of the door.*
>   *His orientation allowed him to see the window while lying prone.*

A substitution probably *could* be made, but it would call for a more convoluted sentence.

Comment: I think think your Cambridge links makes the meanings quite clear, but you missed one subtlety in your explanation. *Orientation* is position of an object in relation to its environment (everything), *direction* is movement or facing *towards* something specific.

Comment: A car sliding sideways is *oriented*, or facing, at right angles to its *direction* of movement.

Answer (score 3):

In geometry, you can represent the orientation by a line and the direction by a Euclidean vector (represented by an arrow).

Comment: "by a line"; Why? Isn't orientation direction?

Comment: I think this is the more precise & concise definition. But this is not specific to 3D, this mention seems useless ;) I Would fix it

Answer (score -3):

*Orientation* means "direction of a thing". For example,

> The building was *oriented* towards north *direction*.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question at hand. I am also not sure I would label "oriented towards north direction" as grammatical.