# What is the male equivalent of Lesbian?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, terminology

There are many terms describing a person who has a sexual preference for members of the same gender. The most clinical of these is homosexual. Other terms include queer and gay, but all of these terms are applied to both men and women indiscriminately.

Lesbian, as far as I can tell, is the only term that is used to describe a person of a gender having a sexual preference for a member of the same gender used exclusively for the female gender.

I have searched around and the closest I have come to an answer is “male gay” or “gay man,” neither of which is sufficient in my mind.

Is there a male equivalent word describing having a same-gender sexual preference, such as lesbian is for women?

Comment: What's wrong with gay man?

Comment: How appropriate that the word   "closest" is mistyped as "closets" :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OP may not get that...but I had a chuckle.

Comment: Dictionary definition: (of a person, especially a man) homosexual

Comment: Related: [“Homosexual” or “Gay and Lesbian”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227708/homosexual-or-gay-and-lesbian) and [Does “gay” necessarily mean male homosexual?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47951/does-gay-necessarily-mean-male-homosexual) and [What is the difference between “Gay” and “Homosexual"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110301/what-is-the-difference-between-gay-and-homosexual-is-it-only-by-gender)

Comment: If everyone is theoretically or figuratively gender neutralized (or is it psychologically neutered?), sexual orientation is reduced to one size fits all, I should think. All the different sexual designations ought to be completely irrelevant to those who promote or subscribe to neutrality, because they're no longer meaningful.

Comment: @Cascabel - Why would simple logic be so provocative? Is there anything illogical about my comment? It wasn't intended to anger you.

Comment: @Cascabel I've already voted to close. Your comment was addressed to me, however.

Comment: @Bread Just responding to your ping. The Q still needs one more DV to close.

Comment: Understand that the terminology used to refer to queer sexuality is fliuid and still being gaily transferred from one island of the language to another, with various terms married to one-another in often unorthodox ways, often with great pride.

Comment: I've heard somewhere that it was normal for Greek men ("lesbian", btw, comes from Greek) to be bisexual, so it was probably more outlandish for women to be homosexual.

Comment: There are many terms for gay men, most if not all invented by straight people and almost all now considered (quite rightly) to be offensive. The word "Lesbian" only acquired its current meaning in the late 19th century and, I suspect, was given that meaning by straight people. I suspect that the only difference between Lesbian and all the aforementioned terms for gay men is that the Lesbian community adopted the term whilst the gay male community did not universally adopt any of the terms describing them. Perhaps this has something to do with the former legal status of the groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Gay* can be inclusive of males and females, or it can apply to males only.  (If the word *gay* always included both sexes, then there would be no need for the *L* in *LGBT*.)

However, unlike *lesbian*, you normally would use *gay* as an adjective and not as a noun.  If you are only talking about men, you might specify *gay men* to be specific about meaning.  If you also discuss women using the word *lesbian*, it would probably be clear from context that the adjective *gay* refers only to men.  But since you would generally need a noun to go with *gay*, you might default to *gay men* anyway and the problem is solved.

But you might want to use a more specific noun, for example to discuss gay men in Canada.  If it's clear that *gay* refers only to males since lesbians are mentioned separately then *gay Canadians* should suffice.  If lesbians aren't mentioned at all and you want specifically to refer to males, then you'd have to say something like *gay Canadian men*.

Answer (score 0):

Uuh...the simplest answer is: There isn't one.
A woman can say:  "I am a lesbian". 
A man cannot say:  "I am a gay".
Both may be a "gay" person, but it seems only women have a gender specific name/noun for them.

Comment: A man might not apply this epithet to **himself,** but "a gay" is known as a pejorative term for a male homosexual and far rarer for women.